# BottomNavigationView overlap in landscape mode

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, landscape-portrait

I have discovered a very strange behavior today. This is my BottomNavigationView.

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/darkPurple"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@color/fillColorDark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_color"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
        tools:ignore="FragmentTagUsage" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is the behavior :

- Launching my app in landscape, all fine
- Launching my app in portrait, all fine
- Launching my app in portrait and then rotate for landscape, bottom bar hide main layout !

If anyone have an idea it gonna be grateful

EDIT : entire layout
EDIT 2 : Add videos

Landscape safe

[image: landscape safe]

Landscape broken

[image: Landscape broken]

Comment: Can you add the rest of the layout?

Comment: Perhaps, your layout is too big to fit into the landscape orientation. And since the bottom app bar will always stay above the content whatever let it be, your content is hidden

Comment: @TheLibrarian I add the entire layout

Comment: @SambhavKhandelwal I agree with you, but when app is launch in landscape i have no problem (i can rotate portrait-landscape several time always fine). But if I launch app in portrait and then rotate, layout gonna be hidden

Comment: @MarineDroit Can you send a video of what happens? Would help us know your problem better

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem 2 years ago.

I have managed to create a custom one purely with XML and no code to avoid this problem.

Link to my old solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61349651/12969368

Comment: I don't know if your solution can fit to my problem. I use several callback like addOnDestinationChangedListener
it works with your custom bar ?